# Number of simultaneous connections supported by web servers

Tags: http, webserver

Does anybody know how to find the simultaneous number of connections allowed on a web server using libcurl or any other ways?

What I want is the number of connections allowed to download a single file from web server on an IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is generally no fixed number and even if there is, it is not announced by some standardized protocol.

Generally, you should used reasonable amounts of connections. If you are performing bulk operations, you should take measures to restrict the traffic and the number of connections you produce, e.,g. by including random delays or using a request queue to restrict the number of open connections.

If you just fire requests with everything you got, you quickly risk being shot into the head by the server provider. Some people (like the stack exchange guys) have developed a pretty low threshold for flipping the kill switch.